# Как поменять mac адрес на windows 10 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mac, subprocess

Можноли как-то поменять mac адрес желательно через cmd чтоб команду можно ввести в subprocess (Просто хочу написать программу для смены mac адреса)

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/mac-address-changer-windows-10/

Comment: https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC